# How do I use a SoupStrainer for attributes that contain dashes?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to use BeautifulSoup and a SoupStrainer to look for specific elements witih attributes in my document.  But how do I do that if the attribute contains a dash?  I would like to do this

```
my_strainer = SoupStrainer('a', data-id="aaa")
```

but this results in the error

```
Can't assign to function call
```

complaining about the "data-id" attribute.  If I change "data-id" to just "id" then everything runs, but then I don't get the results I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it like

```
my_strainer= SoupStrainer('a',{'data-id':'aaa'})
```

`data-*` and other such attributes should be passed like this as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).

Sample

```
html="""
<html class="test">
<a data-id='aaa'>yes</a>
<a>No</a>
<span>no</span>
</html>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
my_strainer= SoupStrainer('a',{'data-id':'aaa'})
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml", parse_only=my_strainer)
print(soup)
```

Output

```
<a data-id="aaa">yes</a>
```